# Type safety when constructing a semi-dynamic object?

Tags: typescript

SOLVED See Below
How would I be able to have a different type assigned to an object property depending on an interface and it's name?

```
interface Type1 {
  property1: string;
}

interface Type2 {
  property2: number;
}

interface Tables {
  table1: Type1;
  table2: Type2;
  table3: Type1; // etc
}

const configuration = {
  table1: {
    // Property 'property1' would be required here
  },
  table2: {
    // Property 'property2' would be required here
  }
  table3: {
    // Property 'property1' would be required here
  }
}
```

My current solution isn't nice and requires as an extra field

```
interface Config {
  [key: string]: {
    type1?: Type1;
    type2?: Type;
  }
}

// Then defining an object...
const configuration {
  Table1: {
    type1: {
      property1: 'value', // Table1 has type safety
    }
  }
}
```

However, above has the intermediate field.

Is it possible to accomplish the first way of doing things?
Or is there a much better solution to getting type safety, the basic idea is to give the user feedback when editing the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require *one and only one of each* (is this a requirement?), but does avoid the extra key and provides some safety around the configurations themselves:

```js
interface Type1 {
  property1: string;
}

interface Type2 {
  property2: number;
}

interface Tables {
  table1: Type1;
  table2: Type2;
  table3: Type1; // etc
}

interface Configuration {
  [index: string]: Type1 | Type2 | Tables;
}

const configuration: Configuration = {
  table1: {
    // Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Type1 | Type2 | Tables'.
  },
  table2: {
    property1: "foo" // Valid
  },
  table3: { // Type '{ table1: { property1: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Tables': table2, table3
    table1: {
      property1: "foo"
    }
  }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECMyDeAsAFDLKZQD22UY6OAXMgM5hSgDmA3CQL4klQkWIhQZsAJgIkyFatDoSmIAK4BbAEbQexfsUHho8JGjgaANhGbTSyMGcuM0WXDrL2LEJc8lu7DiABmJnFXZAB6cOQIMAQ+AWIhI1FkAGFKEBhgDhUoODBgDJsyAG1QABMIAA8mVnYQDgBdEJc8AB8fL2QO1ADmHT0SBAzWZGHM7Nz8wpAmdImcvIKigF5i-08nIlsySM7kAHJ8XgPkYGsQSjBkOGZmbJAAu0o7F0PQ9s6pHr6DgDoZMheAAaQEeSzebZkWRUGh0JwAIhglEoCIiUQAanBzMByoCQWCAsECOj9kcNo4mPhyLCFPRamxOFwgcyTmdrGpzvcGnYABYoZHmcyUADunBp8lowCsyBgVDUr2w71+THBXmBFKCgPcAS22uhcjh9OQSJRCP1ejIel4OiAA)

Comment: It does give you autosuggest of what options are available but if Table1 is type1, it will have required props different than type2.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: turns out this is way overengineered

```
interface ConfigType1 {
  option1: number;
}

interface ConfigType2 {
  option2: number;
}


interface ConfigOptions {
   Prop1: ConfigType1;
   Prop2: ConfigType2;
}

const config: ConfigOptions = {
  Prop1 {
    // this is type of ConfigType1
  }
}
```